# How can you properly convert Swift dictionaries to json and make post requests?

Tags: json, swift, post

This is making post requests, but it is treating the json as a string, which shows up on the server as (stuff): ''. I don't know how to fix it. (When I used python to implement this, it was perfect.)

```
    let json: [String: Any] = ["id": 1, "checksum": "hey"]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    /*print(jsonData!)
    let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: [])
    print(parsedData!)*/
    //print(parsedData)


    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: "http://10.240.81.23:3000/updateProfile")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: What is treating the JSON as a string? What is the question you are trying to ask? Is there a specific line giving you trouble?

Comment: Maybe AFNetworking is for you? https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. So the responseJSON object ends up as a String?

Comment: At least you have to specify Content-Type in the header, otherwise the server has no idea how to process you request

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for networking, it is amazingly easy to use and works great. Also [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) that makes JSON parsing and manipulation really easy and optional-safe.

You can use [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) to install those two frameworks easily.